# Webcam Iris Detection with Hough Circles in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, canny-operator

I have managed to isolate a very specific bounding region for an eye with the help of dlib's facial landmark detector. However, I am not completely stumped on how to create a circular border around the iris itself. I have tried canny edge detection followed by hough circles but hough circles does not seem to be able to process the image, most likely due to the low resolution and partially obstructed iris (due to the eye lids of course). I have tried this with a higher resolution camera feed and it works, but due to the constraints of my project, it is not feasible to do this. Currently, this is the bounding region I have isolated.

The first image is the eye looking straight at the webcam as shown below:

[image]

The image below is the eye looking upwards:

[image]

I am not looking for code, but if anyone could guide me as to what transformations on the image would be appropriate, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a threshold on the region before using the edge detector. Then you could use the hough circle transformation. If this does not work, an alternativ emay be to find contours and analyse the contour with cvFitEllipse

Comment: Hmm. So I used a threshold and got this. Is there any way to remove the edge around the eye?
http://puu.sh/q9dGT/d5ff23f0c4.png

Comment: what kind of threshold did you use? my intend would be to remove the white of the eye isolating the rest. try using a histogram to find the best threshold value